# How can I sort the output files of my code numerically

Tags: python, sorting, printing

I've seen quite a few posts in the past detailing how to do this with

```
    sorted(path, key=lambda, etc)
```

But I cant seem to get mine to work. My code is starting with:

```
import os

mypath = '../Assessment_Scenarios/Simulations1400/'
currentPath = os.getcwd( )
print currentPath

out_directory = os.listdir(mypath)
outfile = open("scan results//frequency criteria test.txt","w")
    
existingProgressFiles = []
for file in out_directory:
    if file[-3:] == "txt":
        existingProgressFiles.append(file)

for fileName in existingProgressFiles:


    fileName = mypath + fileName
    outfile.write( "#--------------------------------------------------------------------------#\n")
    outfile.write( "processing: " + fileName + "\n")
    infile = open(fileName,"r")
    lines = infile.readlines()
    infile.close()


    totalLines = len(lines)
    print "file: ", fileName, " processing ", totalLines, " records."
    data = []
```

Here are the exact names of two of the files which have an error for sorting:

Fault_100.txt

Fault_1000.txt

There is much more code under this. Basically this program is taking a certain index from a notepad file and listing the top 10 highest numbers in descending order, taking into account absolute value. I was able to properly sort the output of each file. But the file names (there are 1400 files in total) are going from 98, 99, 100, 1001, 1002. Instead of going from 100 to 101. Here is an example.

processing: '../Assessment_Scenarios/Simulations1400/FAULT_100.txt

then it will go straight to fault _1000 like this

processing: '../Assessment_Scenarios/Simulations1400/FAULT_1000.txt

Does anyone know how I would edit the "print currentpath" to make the file numbers print in acsending numerical order?

thank you.

I tried sorted on the currentpath

```
    print sorted(currentpath, key=lambda k:k[1]))
```

The code errors out, I don't think the k values are correct maybe. I have 1400 files in total.

thank you.

So i've tried the following:

```
import os
mypath = '../Assessment_Scenarios/Simulations1400/'
currentPath = os.getcwd( )
print sorted(currentPath, key=lambda fn: tuple(int(s) for s in re.findall('[0-9]+',fn)))
```

Comment: `k[1]` is the second character of the element. If you want to sort by the number in `FAULT_100`, you need to use `int(k.split('_')[1])`

Comment: Search for "natural sort" and you'll find lots of solutions.

Comment: I tried importing the natsort database and it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the filenames themselves but only the numbers contained within, it's quite easy to make `sorted` do what you want:

```
import re
sorted_files = sorted(existingProgressFiles, key=lambda fn: tuple(int(s) for s in re.findall('[0-9]+', fn)))
for fileName in sorted_files:
```

Comment: Hey Mark, thanks for you comment. That's right, I dont care about the file names, just the numbers contained within. Each file is called Fault_001.txt all the way to _1400. I tried the code you mentioned and it didn't work. Is there a reason you have "import re" instead of "import os" like I had?

Comment: @JMFcode I use `re` because it gives me groups of digits.  You have to be more specific than "it didn't work", can you edit your question and add two specific examples of strings that are sorting in the wrong order?

Comment: The command prompt exits out in a few milliseconds. It doesn't even give an error. I'm trying to understand exactly what you mean by specific examples of strings. I am new to this as you can tell. Basically, it is sorting the output file names incorrectly by going from 99 > 100 > 1000 instead of from 100 > 101. It is referencing a path with 1400 .txt files.

Comment: @JMFcode take just two of those file names that are sorting incorrectly and put them into a list.  Run the code in my answer against that list and tell me the result, and put those *exact* filenames into the question.

Comment: Mark, to be honest. I'm not exactly sure how to do what you requested. I do however think I left how a huge chunk of code that was important to my question. I updated my question with the rest of the code.

Comment: @JMFcode thanks for the code update, but it doesn't help.  We need to see the *data* which we can't because we don't have your files.  The contents of `existingProgressFiles` specifically, narrowed down to just two files.  Two files that you don't believe sort correctly.

Comment: I believe I may have put what you're looking for in my question under the code. The actual txt files are huge (70,000 KB). If this wasn't what you're looking for. Could we start a chat if you have the time?

Comment: @JMFcode I just noticed that your larger code sample doesn't include any sorting.  How do you expect to get a sorted list without using `sort` or `sorted`?  The size of the files doesn't matter, all you're working with at the moment is the file names which are small.

Comment: So, I tried using sorted on the following line of code:  print "file: ", sorted(fileName), " processing ", totalLines, " records.". My code still ran, the command prompt did become all jumbled with random letters instead of the usual "processing: '../Assessment_Scenarios/Simulations1400/FAULT_001.txt"  text that appears. The output still remained the same as before I used "sorted".

Comment: @JMFcode sorting a single string will only give you a list of characters.  You need to use `sorted` in your `for` loop with the entire list of filenames.

Comment: So I tried using your "sorted(unsorted_files, key=lambda fn: tuple(int(s) for s in re.findall('[0-9]+', fn)))"  in the for loop where fileName is being defined. So I did this basically. Define re fileName = mypath + sorted(fileName, key=lambda fn: tuple(int(s) for s in re.findall('[0-9]+', fn))). The command prompt exits out immediately.

Comment: @JMFcode I've updated my example so it should be clear exactly what I meant.

Comment: Mark, it works!!! thank you so much for being patient with me..